# Explicit formula versus symbolic derivatives in R

Tags: r, derivative

I would like to evaluate higher order derivatives of some function *f* in **R**.
Two possibilities are available to me.

1. Either I determine a general expression for *f<sup>(k)</sup>*, the *k*-th derivative of *f* (which I can do in my particular case), and then I evaluate it;
2. Or I take advantage of the capacities of **R** to perform symbolic derivative (function *D()*).

What are the advantages of 1 over 2? Let us say that *f<sup>(k)</sup>* is not a recursive formula. What if *f<sup>(k)</sup>* is recursive?

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Your questions are unclear.  Yes, Ryacas and other algebraic computer languages can calculate analytic (not "symbolic" derivatives (not "derivation"), and yes you can make R calculate the value of various functions which represent derivatives.  But why, and for what set of functions `f` ?

Comment: I do speak about "symbolic" derivatives in R (try help(D)). 
"Why" would be too long and unrelevant to explain.
"For what set of functions f"... well, let us say any function for which derivatives can be computed...
I would like to know what advantages you would point out, e.g., in terms of computing time, memory, speed,...

Comment: @G. Grothendieck: Thank you very much for your comments

Comment: @G.Grothendieck -- Thanks for chiming in. Would you consider making your comments an answer, and/or mentioning if there is any other advantage of Ryacas over D() w.r.t. symbolic differentiation? The help page for `D()` lists a number of single variable functions that it recognizes. Does Ryacas recognize a bunch more?

Comment: ok, I have deleted my comments and transferred them to an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Symbolic differentiation is less error prone than doing it by hand.

For low orders I would not think that symbolic differentiation would take much computer time but you can readily time your specific situation to determine what it is using [proc.time](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/proc.time.html), [system.time](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/system.time.html) or the [rbenchmark](http://rbenchmark.googlecode.com) package.  Also see [these examples](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/timing_code.htm).

You might want to try both symbolic and hand differentiation as a check.

Regarding R's [deriv](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/deriv.html) (and associated functions such as `D`) vs. the [Ryacas](http://ryacas.googlecode.com) package, the latter has the facility to do repeated differentiation without requiring that the user iterate themselves (third arg of `deriv` specifies the order) and it has a `Simplify` function for which no counterpart exists in R although Ryacas should be carefully checked since yacas can be a bit buggy at times.

Here is an example:

```
> library(Ryacas)
> x <- Sym("x")
> y <- (x^2+x)^2
> dy <- deriv(y, x, 2) # 2nd deriv
> dy
expression(2 * (2 * x + 1)^2 + 4 * (x^2 + x))
> Simplify(dy)
expression(2 * (6 * x^2 + 6 * x + 1))
```

EDIT: Added to example:

```
> Eval(dy, list(x = 3))
[1] 146
> Eval(Simplify(dy), list(x = 3))
[1] 146
>
> f <- function(x) {}
> body(f) <- yacas(Simplify(dy))[[1]]
> f
function (x) 
2 * (6 * x^2 + 6 * x + 1)
> f(3)
[1] 146
>
> # double check
> w <- 3
> eval(D( D(expression((w^2+w)^2), "w"), "w"))
[1] 146
```

Also try `demo("Ryacas-Function")` .

EDIT 2: Fixed an error and added more to the example.