# Stochastic Gradient Descent on Custom Functions

Tags: r, machine-learning, optimization, gradient-descent

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to perform Stochastic Gradient Descent on custom defined functions.

For instance, here is an example of using Gradient Descent to optimize a custom function (using the well established "pracma" library):

```
# define function:

  Rastrigin <- function(x)
    {
        return(20 + x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*x[1]) + cos(2*pi*x[2])))
    }

# run gradient descent:

library(pracma)

> steep_descent(c(1, 1), Rastrigin)

$xmin
[1] 0.9949586 0.9949586

$fmin
[1] 1.989918

$niter
[1] 3
```

Now, I am trying to run Stochastic Gradient Descent on this same function. I found the following package that allow for Stochastic Gradient Descent (e.g. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sgd/versions/1.1.1, https://rdrr.io/cran/torch/man/optim_rmsprop.html) - but this seems to more suited for functions within pre-existing statistical and machine learning models. I also tried looking for popular variants of Stochastic Gradient Descent such as ADAGRAD or RMSPROP, **but there does not seem to be any straightforward methods to implement Stochastic Gradient Descent on custom defined functions.**

For instance - suppose I wanted to run Stochastic Gradient Descent on the "Rastrigin" function that I defined above; how to do this?

Thanks!

**Note:** I understand that performing Gradient Descent on a function requires knowledge of the function's derivatives. From the this Stackoverflow post ([Explicit formula versus symbolic derivatives in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779362/explicit-formula-versus-symbolic-derivatives-in-r)), we can obtain the derivatives of the Rastrign Function:

```
#load libraries
library(Ryacas0)
library(Ryacas)

#define Rastrign function (here I am defining the function in "x" and "y" instead of "x[1] and x[2]"

z <- 20 + x^2 + y^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*x) + cos(2*pi*y))
x <- Sym("x")
y <- Sym("y")

#first derivative with respect to x (note : 2 * pi = 6.283)
dx <- deriv(z, x, 1) 

dx

yacas_expression(2 * x - -62.83185307 * sin(6.28318530717959 * x))

#first derivative with respect to y
 dy <- deriv(z, y, 1) 

 dy

yacas_expression(2 * y - -62.83185307 * sin(6.28318530717959 * y))
```

**Now that we know the first derivatives of the Rastrign Function with respect to "x" and "y" - can we write a function that performs Stochastic Gradient Descent on the Rastrign Function in R?**

Comment: What you are looking is called Automatic Differentiation, and most DL frameworks use it.

Comment: @ Dr Snoopy: thank you for your reply! If you have time, could you please show me how to optimize this function? Thanks!

Comment: Don't think that SGD is really pertinent here. You use it when your objective function is a sum of many independent terms and you just evaluate the gradient on the sum of a subset of those terms. The terms above are usually the cost function calculated for each data point of a dataset. Here you neither have data points nor an objective function with many terms, so don't think using SGD makes much sense.

Comment: @ nicola: thank you for your reply! I understood your point, I was just interested in seeing if it could work anyways for a problem like this?

Comment: I agree with @nicola.  SGD is meant for fitting a model to data, where the objective function is the sum of squares error over hundreds of data points (actual - predicted)^2).  To minimize this function, I would recommend optim from base R with method = "BFGS".

Comment: @ Arthur: thank you for your reply! I also fuly agree ... i just wanted to see if this can be done anyways